# How do I get just the name of the file from the path?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm saving something from winform to a file, with SaveFileDialog (svf), and I would like to use the name of the file, after saving, how can I do it?

```
sfd.FileName;
```

It's not the right way, because it has got the path too... (for example:c:/asd/asd/asd.doc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `Path.GetFileName()` to get just the filename.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sfd.FileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the various [`Path` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) to split the path into the various components you need.

In this case it's [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(sfd.FileName);
```